# Alternative to deprecated jQuery .toggle() function in menu button animation

Tags: jquery, animation, menu, toggle, deprecated

The navigation menu button animation on a site I built a few years ago has recently broken due to the .toggle() function being deprecated and I can't work out what to replace the code with, any help would be great appreciated!

Here is a link to the site (the animation to open and close the menu is top right):
http://blackcurrent.co/#home

When you click the menu button, the symbol is supposed to animate as the menu opens, and then when you click the same button to close it again, the animation should fire again but in reverse.

Here is the jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#bespokeButton').toggle(
function(){
    jQuery("#segment1").removeClass('seg1ani2');
    jQuery("#segment1").toggleClass('seg1ani');
    jQuery("#segment2Container").removeClass('seg2Contani2');
    jQuery("#segment2Container").toggleClass('seg2Contani');
    jQuery("#segment3").removeClass('seg3ani2');
    jQuery("#segment3").toggleClass('seg3ani');
},
function(){
    jQuery("#segment1").removeClass('seg1ani');
    jQuery("#segment1").toggleClass('seg1ani2');
    jQuery("#segment2Container").removeClass('seg2Contani');
    jQuery("#segment2Container").toggleClass('seg2Contani2');
    jQuery("#segment3").removeClass('seg3ani');
    jQuery("#segment3").toggleClass('seg3ani2');
});
    });
</script>
```

I have changed the .toggle() function to .click() and as you can see on the site now the menu button animates as it should to open the menu, but when you click to close the menu again it does not fire the reverse animation.

Any ideas how I can get it to do so again?

Many thanks,

N

Comment: Save the state of the menu with a class like `expanded` on a common parent to all animated elements. On click check with `hasClass()` if the navigation is expanded or not and then toggle your classes accordingly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One simple approach is to toggle a class on the button and check if class exists or not.

```
function openMenu(){
    jQuery("#segment1").removeClass('seg1ani2');
    jQuery("#segment1").toggleClass('seg1ani');
    jQuery("#segment2Container").removeClass('seg2Contani2');
    jQuery("#segment2Container").toggleClass('seg2Contani');
    jQuery("#segment3").removeClass('seg3ani2');
    jQuery("#segment3").toggleClass('seg3ani');
}

function closeMenu(){
    jQuery("#segment1").removeClass('seg1ani');
    jQuery("#segment1").toggleClass('seg1ani2');
    jQuery("#segment2Container").removeClass('seg2Contani');
    jQuery("#segment2Container").toggleClass('seg2Contani2');
    jQuery("#segment3").removeClass('seg3ani');
    jQuery("#segment3").toggleClass('seg3ani2');
}


jQuery('#bespokeButton').click(function(e){
    if($(this).hasClass('open')){
      closeMenu()
    }else{
      openMenu()
    }
    $(this).toggleClass('open')
});
```

Comment: Excellent, works like a treat, thank you very much!